# Monopoly Matrix Coding

Tags: markov-chains

I am an IB student doing SL math. For my math IA i picked the topic of monopoly and the optimal way to play. However, in this IA there is a massive matrix that needs to be built to see how the long term possibilities of landing on a given square. I found someone's code on this page https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.1107.pdf, but I don't know how to code it. I took a grade 11 course in computer science, but I barely know anything LOL. I used visual studio in this class, and I hope that I can use visual studio to code this. Can someone help? I have no idea if it's possible. thanks guys!

Comment: If and when you don't know how to start solving as task or even researching it, make sure you have a description that you are confident to understand even a year after. Try to fix equally clear how to check the task is accomplished.

Comment: Do you understand what the eigenvalues of a matrix are?